# Error while closing the output stream in order to commit response. org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish

i am using glassfish 4.1  and  jersey core 1.19
Error while closing the output stream in order to commit response.

> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
>   java.lang.InterruptedException at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.getResponseContext(ResponseWriter.java:275)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.writeResponseStatusAndHeaders(ResponseWriter.java:148)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder$1.getOutputStream(ServerRuntime.java:611)

Comment: And the code causing the exception?

Comment: OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();           os.write(data.toString().getBytes());
if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream()),"UTF-8"));
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            result=output;
            }
            conn.disconnect();